# Prime ideal in ${\bf Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

I firstly introduce definition of prime ideal.

> Ideal $P$ in the commutative ring is **prime** if $$ ab\in P\Rightarrow a\in P\ {\it or}\ b\in P$$

$(2)$ is prime ideal in ${\bf Z}$. That is, if $6=2\cdot 3\in (2)$ then $$ 3\in (2)\ {\it or}\ 2\in (2).$$

Note that ${\bf Z}$ is PID. That is, every ideal is a **principal** ideal.

Here my question is:

> Show that $$P=(\overline{x},\overline{y})\subset R={\bf Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$$ is prime.

**MY TRY** : $y=\frac{z^2}{x}$ so that in $R$, $$ x^ky^mz^l= x^{k-m} z^{l+2m}$$

Hence $R={\bf Q}[x,\frac{1}{x},z]=P\oplus {\bf Q}[\frac{1}{x}]$

Hence any element in $R$ has the form $ab$ where $(a\in P$ or $b\in P)$ or $(a=
\frac{1}{x^m},\ b=\frac{1}{x^l})$.

This completes the proof. Am I right ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal you point out is not prime because the quotient is $\Bbb{Q}[z]/(z^2)$ which is not a domain. Perhaps you should revise your question.

Comment: I do not understand why would the quotient be $\Bbb{Q}[z]/(z^2)$ could you please help me.. what quotient are you talking about $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ or $(\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2))/((\bar{x},\bar{y})/((xy-z^2)))$.. I guess it is $(\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2))/((\bar{x},\bar{y})/((xy-z^2)))$ we know that $(\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2))/((\bar{x},\bar{y})/((xy-z^2)))\cong \Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(\bar{x},\bar{y})$.. this is under modulo $(xy-z^2)$ so we would have $xy=z^2$ in some sense but then.. I am confused... please help me..

Comment: I believe that your opinion is not correct. $(xy-z^2)$ is not contained in $(x,y)$ Am I right ?   And $R/P = {\bf Q}[x,y,z]/(x,y,xy-z^2)={\bf Q}[z]/(z^2)$ So $zz=0$ so that $z$ is zero divisor Hence $R/P$ is not integral domain.

Answer (score 0):

First, a correction: a PID is an integral domain where every ideal **is** (not: is contained in) a principal ideal.

As for your question, my hint to you is to use the fact that $p\subset A$ is prime if, and only if $A/p$ is an integral domain.